# setup background color for all app with using sherloack bar

Tags: android, user-interface, actionbarsherlock, background-color

I want to set up for my all my  activity's background white.
Still didnt find the way how to do is simple and that it will change my text color to black.
I am using sherloack bar on some my activity's and I think that's my problem.
My manifest looks like that:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/rss"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
         >
        <activity
            android:name=".ListRss"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_listr_rss"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="RssItem" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="editRss.AddNewRss">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="openRssItem.WebActivity" >
```

where my style

```
   <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
         <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>
```

and my activity for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/BackgroundColor"
android:id="@+id/myScreen">
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/rss" />
```

will glade to receive a simple solution that solve the background color to white and the text for black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `android:Theme` as the parent theme of your theme, if you want to use ActionBarSherlock(unless you want to override everything...).
If you want to have the light theme you have to use this:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
[...]
</style>
```